# Twilio not executing flow

Tags: twilio

I have a flow set up so when a user calls:

1. Phone A rings
2. If Phone A does not pick up after 4 seconds, Phone B rings
3. If Phone B does not pick up a voicemail message plays
4. Caller has an option to leave a voicemail that gets emailed to us

The flow is not executing. When one dials, both phones dial at the same time and do not play the voicemail. Any ideas?

[Screenshot of the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/165DR.png)

I have looked at the logs for the flow and it is not detecting any incoming calls despite testing it.

Comment: Did you check the phone number configuration that it's pointed to your studio flow? The fact that the logs is not detecting an incoming call makes no sense, so I would start with validating that the pieces are configured correctly and then digging into the flow piece.

Comment: Can you take a look at the [studio logs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/studio-troubleshooting#logs)? You can see all the data going in and out of the widgets. There may be something off that you can spot there